# Cant link boost library with g++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost, g++

I'm trying to build the following code:

**Content of "Source.cpp"**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   path myPath("foo");

   if (exists(myPath)) ...
}
```

The command that I use to compile it is:

```
g++ -Wall -I D:\boost_1_72_0 Source.cpp -o test -L D:\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib -lboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72
```

But I get default unresolved symbol errors:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccskBqAh.o:Source.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEE[__ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEE]+0x7): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
... etc
```

There's no problem when I compile it with Visual Studio though.

P.s. Space after "-L" and "-I" is allowed. And I've tried to link different libs. For shared I also used #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK just in case.

**Shared:**

```
boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72
boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72
boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x32-1_72
boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_72
```

**Static:**

```
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-sgd-x32-1_72
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_72
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-s-x32-1_72
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_72
libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_72
```

Comment: Doesn't `vc142` in `boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x32` mean this library was built for MSVC? If so, it's not compatible with MinGW. You need a version built for MinGW.

Comment: You need to build boost with the compiler you are using. Visual Studio binaries are no use.

Comment: I'd suggest installing MSYS2. You'll get a prebuilt Boost and a fresh version of GCC as a bonus.

Comment: Those are Visual Studio 2019 libraries (free for most users!). You will need to get or build your own, building Boost from source is not that hard, there are [step by step instructions on the site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/more/getting_started/windows.html), although Boost doesn't appear to officially support MSYS.

Comment: Thx, I chose toolset=gcc and built libs I needed. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Visual Studio` binaries for boost are incompatible with `MinGW`. You will need boost binaries that were produced with your toolchain. While many `c` libraries can use binaries produced by other `c` compilers `c++` libraries are generally not compatible.

The following question explains the difficulties of ABI incompatibility in `c++`:
[Easy way to guarantee binary compatibility for C++ library, C linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752971/easy-way-to-guarantee-binary-compatibility-for-c-library-c-linkage)